# Qt : Qwidget size

Tags: qt, size, qwidget

I am writing a program with Qt that looks like this:

[image: screen capture]

The main window is a class `Window : QWidget` that I have defined. It has a `QGridLayout` which basically has 1 row and 3 columns. As you can see, the first column contains a menu (which is a class `Menu  :QWidget`), the second and third columns each contain a canvas (a class `Canvas : QWidget` that I have also defined).

I am having a really hard time trying to figure out how the sizes work. So far, I have just defined a minimum size for the first column's width (in my window's layout) to fix the menu's width, and I have set a fixed size for `Canvas` in its constructor (like this: `setFixedSize(QSize(size_in_pixels, size_in_pixels));`).

The problem is of course that this behaves badly under rescaling the window by the user. I guess what I would like to do is sort of set my canvas's `sizeHint` to `size_in_pixels` (my preferred size) but this hardly seems possible. I would also like my canvases to have same height and width at all times. I have been reading Qt documentation and trying several things but I can't come up with a solution.

What would be the way to go according to you? Thanks a lot for your insights.

Comment: I submitted an answer...but as @karlphillip suggested, please please please accept some of your previous answers.

Comment: Duely noted! I am new to this website. jdi, thank you so much for your answer. I'll tell you how it works out in a few moments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just set the canvas widgets to an `Expanding` size policy. They will equally consume the remaining space as the layout increases in size.

Here is an example, written in PyQt4

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.resize(800,600)
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)

label = QtGui.QLabel("Menu")
label.setFrameStyle(label.Box)
label.setMinimumWidth(100)
layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0)

label = QtGui.QLabel("Canvas 1")
label.setFrameStyle(label.Box)
policy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
label.setSizePolicy(policy)
layout.addWidget(label, 0, 1)

label = QtGui.QLabel("Canvas 2")
label.setFrameStyle(label.Box)
layout.addWidget(label, 0, 2)
policy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
label.setSizePolicy(policy)
```

[image: small]

[image: larger]

Comment: this is great, looks like I'm going to be able to work with this. thanks a lot!